# Binary search for lowest index of an element

Tags: python, binary-search

I want to implement a binary search function which returns the lowest index of the element to be searched. Here is my code:

```
def binarySearch(arr,x):
    n=len(arr)
    if n==1:
        if arr[0]==x:
            return 0
        else:
            return -1 # not in list
    else:
        m=int(n/2)
        if x <= arr[m]:
            return binarySearch(arr[:m],x)
        else:
            return m+binarySearch(arr[m+1:],x)
```

However, this doesn't work correctly. Can someone help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Binary search (bisection) in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212358/binary-search-bisection-in-python)

Comment: yeah , cool . But I don't want to use bisect_left . Any suggestions ?

Comment: I don't understand. Can u show me which part of the code ?

Comment: n=len(arr) is not needed, just add the logic to the if statement below

Comment: u mean to change the if statement from if n == 1 to len(arr) == 1 ?

Comment: Sorry, I should have added that as an edit to the comments, it is more to make the code concise. It doesn't help you understand the part about the m start index

Comment: When I run your code, I get     IndexError: list index out of range. You don't seem to have anything terminating the code? if you have the list arr = [1,2,3,3,4], you would get m=2 on the first try, but instead of accepting that the value was found, your code would recursively call the function again, this time with a list of arr=[1,2].

Comment: Now, you would no longer find the element as it is no longer in the list segment being searched. Explicitly have a condition for when  arr[m] = x, when it is less than x, and finally when it is greater than x.

Comment: Can you show me that with a piece of code ?

Answer (score 1):

```
def binarySearch(arr,x):

    if len(arr) == 0:
        return 0

    else:
        m=int(len(arr)/2)

        if arr[m] == x:
            c = 1

            while arr[m-c] == x:
                c += 1
            return m-c+1

        else:
            if x < arr[m]:
                return binarySearch(arr[:m],x)
            else:
                return binarySearch(arr[m+1:],x)
```

This fixes your issues while also giving you the lowest index

Comment: Special casing `arr[m-1]` won't work in the general case.  `binarySearch([1,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4], 3)` gives `3` instead of `2`.

Comment: Does that fix it? I have to get back to work and that's the quickest hack I can think of.

Comment: Nice, that looks better to me.  Runtime is no longer logarithmic, tho I'm not sure if that can be guaranteed given OP's question.

Comment: yeah , its a good solution , but as wildwilhelm mentioned ,it isn't in log(n) :/

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10148849/find-lowest-index-of-a-given-value-in-a-presorted-array) seems to be a good solution to your problem. The array is edited to sections that are likely to contain the value.  With the array [1,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4], my solution takes 0.0001163482666015625 while his takes 6.198883056640625e-06.

Comment: but I'm asked for an implemention of algorithm in log(n)

Comment: The selected answer for the question is log(n).

Comment: The solution posted by the OP in the thread is similar to mine, where it becomes roughly O(n) at the worst case. The selected answer improves on it by changing the binary search itself.

Answer (score 1):

Time Complexity: `O(log(n))`
Space Complexity: `O(1)`

```
def index_equals_value_search(arr):

  left, right = 0, len(arr)-1
  lowest = -float('inf')
  while left<=right:   

    mid = (left+right)//2   
    print(mid, left, right, arr[mid])
    if arr[mid] == mid:     
      lowest = min(lowest, mid)
      right = mid-1
    elif arr[mid]<0:
       left = mid+1
    elif arr[mid]<mid:
      left = mid+1
    elif arr[mid]>mid:
      right = mid-1


  if lowest == -float('inf'): 
    return -1
  return lowest


arr = [-6,-5,-4,-1,1,3,5,7]
index_equals_value_search(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the index of *an element* which is equal to `x` by just adding a test for equality into the `else` part of your function:

```
def binarySearch(arr,x):
    n=len(arr)
    if n==1:
        if arr[0]==x:
            return 0
        else:
            return -1 # not in list
    else:
        m = int(n/2)
        if x < arr[m]:
            return binarySearch(arr[:m],x)
        elif x == arr[m]:
            return m
        else:
            return m + binarySearch(arr[m+1:],x)
```

This prevents the problem of recursing past the solution, mentioned by @Fruitpunchsalami

However, this won't get you the *lowest* index:

```
>>> binarySearch([1,2,3,3,4,4], 3)
3
```

Here the right answer would be 2.

A further problem is the handling of elements which are not found, due to the special case of `-1`.  We get:

```
>>> binarySearch([1,2,3,3,6,6], 4)
2
```

I would be tempted to suggest a generic solution whereby you find the index of the largest element less than `x`, and then check the element in the position one up from that one.

Finding the largest element less than `x` can be done in logarithmic time; checking the element to the right is constant time, so you still get O(log n):

```
def binarySearch(arr,x):
    '''Returns the lowest index of the element equal to `x` or NaN if not found.'''
    def innerBinarySearch(arr, x):
        '''Find index of largest element strictly less than `x`.'''
        if len(arr) == 0:
            return -1
        m = len(arr) // 2
        if x <= arr[m]:
            return innerBinarySearch(arr[:m], x)
        else:
            return m + 1 + innerBinarySearch(arr[m + 1:], x)

    idx = innerBinarySearch(arr,x) + 1
    if 0 <= idx < len(arr) and arr[idx] == x:
        return idx
    return float('nan')
```

Do it all in one function:

```
def binarySearch(arr,x):
    '''Returns the lowest index of the element equal to `x` or NaN if not found.'''
    if len(arr) == 0:
        return float('nan')
    m = len(arr) // 2
    if arr[m] < x:
        return m + 1 + binarySearch(arr[m + 1:], x)
    elif x < arr[m] or (0 < m and arr[m-1] == x):
        return binarySearch(arr[:m], x)
    else:
        return m
```

Comment: Thank for the suggestion , but my function must find the lowest index. Do you know , how to change the code to find it ?

Comment: what does if not arr mean ?

Comment: Here it means that arr is empty.

Comment: so your last piece of code should be the right implementation ?

Comment: When I try to run it , it gives me this error ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() for the if not arr

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise you were using numpy arrays.  `len(arr) == 0` should work better.

Comment: Yes, thanks, this works :) have you got any idea how to transform my code in this way without two functions and when the element isnt in the array to return NaN?

Comment: (edit) We can just stuff the one function inside the other.

Comment: So there isnt any way without the defintion of a new function

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10148989/1062499) does it in O(log N) time and using a single function.

Comment: Yes but can it be so edited, that it doesnt require the inner function

Comment: (edit) OK, one recursive function, cribbed from the other answer.

Comment: Thank you for the solution :)